# In query with joins and multi-table/field ORDER BY, how to set LIMIT offset to start from a particular row identified by a unique id field?

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit, offset, row-number

Suppose I have four tables: `tbl1` ... `tbl4`. Each has a unique numerical `id` field. `tbl1`, `tbl2` and `tbl3` each has a foreign key field for the next table in the sequence. E.g. `tbl1` has a `tbl2_id` foreign key field, and so on. Each table also has a field `order` (and other fields not relevant to the question).

It is straightforward to join all four tables to return all rows of tbl1 together with corresponding fields from the other three fields. It is also easy to order this result set by a specific `ORDER BY` combination of the `order` fields. It is also easy to return just the row that corresponds to some particular `id` in `tbl1`, e.g. `WHERE tbl1.id = 7777`.

QUESTION: what query most efficiently returns (e.g.) 100 rows, starting from the row corresponding to `id=7777`, **in the order determined by the specific combination of `order` fields**?

Using `ROW_NUMBER` or (an emulation of it in MySQL version < 8) to get the position of the id=7777 row, and then using that in a new version of the same query to set the offset in the `LIMIT` clause would be one approach. (With a read lock in between.) But can it be done in a single query?

```
# FIRST QUERY: get row number of result row where tbl1.id = 7777

SELECT x.row_number 
FROM 
   (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, tbl1.id AS id
    FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t, tbl1
    INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.tbl2_id
    INNER JOIN tbl3 ON tbl3.id = tbl2.tbl3_id
    INNER JOIN tbl4 ON tbl4.id = tbl3.tbl4_id
    WHERE <some conditions>
    ORDER BY tbl4.order, tbl3.order, tbl2.order, tbl1.order
   ) AS x 
WHERE id=7777;
```

Store the row number from the above query and use it to bind `:offset` in the following query.

```
# SECOND QUERY : Get 100 rows starting from the one with id=7777

SELECT x.field1, x.field2, <etc.> 
FROM 
  (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, field1, field2
   FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t, tbl1
   INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.tbl2_id
   INNER JOIN tbl3 ON tbl3.id = tbl2.tbl3_id
   INNER JOIN tbl4 ON tbl4.id = tbl3.tbl4_id
   WHERE <same conditions as before>
   ORDER BY tbl4.order, tbl3.order, tbl2.order, tbl1.order
  ) AS x 
LIMIT :offset, 100;
```

Comment: Ordering is ordering, how will you determine `most efficient`? Please provide the DDL of the 4 tables an sample data (as inserts)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. You are right that "most efficient" is vague. I was wondering whether this seemed like a known pattern to anyone, with recognized good ways and bad ways of doing it, before I try to implement it.

Comment: I feel it should be noted that the @row_number technique used in older versions of MySQL appears to work but isn't guaranteed to do so apparently (i.e. considered a hack by some) From MySQL 8 onward, and in many other dbms's,  use of `row_number() over(partition by ... order by ...)` would be preferable. Doubt it make much difference to the specifics of this question however.

Answer (score 1):

**Clarify question**

In the general case, you won't ask for `WHERE id1 > 7777`.  Instead, you have a tuple of `(11,22,33,44)` and you want to "continue where you left off".

**Two discussions, with**

That is messy, but not impossible.  See [Iterating through a compound key](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#iterating_through_a_compound_key) .  Ig gives an example of doing it with 2 columns; 4 columns coming from 4 tables is an extension of such.

**A variation**

Here is another discussion of such:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164428/should-i-store-data-pre-ordered-rather-than-ordering-on-the-fly/164755#164755

In actually implementing such, I have found that letting the "100" (`LIMIT`) be flexible can be easier to think through.  The idea is: reach forward 100 rows (with `LIMIT 100,1`).  Let's say you get (111,222,333,444).  If you are currently at (111, ...), then deal with id2/3/4.  If it is, say, (113, ...), then do `WHERE id1 < 113` and leave off any specification of id2/3/4.  This means fetching less than 100 rows, but it lands you just shy of starting id1=113.

That is, it involves constructing a `WHERE` clause with between 1 and 4 conditions.

In all cases, your query says `ORDER BY id1, id2, id3, id4`.  And the only use for `LIMIT` is in the probe to figure out how far ahead the 100th row is (with `LIMIT 100,1`).

I think I can dig out some old Perl code for that.

Comment: Many thanks @Rick. And also for the link to your collections of solutions to problems. Having read your reply, I think I should have described the real-world problem for which this is a candidate solution. Your answers are very helpful, but don't quite match the description of the problem (my fault - not yours). Rather than trying to do a big edit of the original question, I'll put some clarifying comments here.

Comment: Re: **Clarify Question** I don't want `WHERE id > 7777` because I am not looking for blocks of sequential ids. The id fields are (effectively random) unique ids. The ordering I am interested in is on the `order` fields of the tables. I use e.g. `tbl1.id = 7777` to pick out a single row of tbl1, and I want to know the next 100 rows according to the ordering that results from the `JOIN` in the subquery in my examples. The method in your first link, "Iterating through a complex key", would involve quite a complex AND/OR expression for 4 tables. I think it would be correct, and will try.

Comment: Re: **Clarify question** Here is a toy example of what I am trying to conceptualize. We are trying to restore a multivolume book that has been shredded horizontally. We have a collection of shreds. Each shred has a horizontal line of words on it. Words are ordered in the usual way within the shred. words = `tbl1` shreds = `tbl2` numerical ordering of words within containing shred = `tbl1.order`. Since each shred comes from exactly one page, we reconstruct pages by grouping ordered sequences of shreds. The database tracks the current state of our reconstruction. ...

Comment: Re: **Clarify question** 
... pages = `tbl3` numerical ordering of shreds within containing page = `tbl2.order`. Similarly, we reconstruct the order (`tbl3.order`) of pages (`tbl3` rows) within the bound volumes (`tbl4` rows) that originally contained them, and we reconstruct the sequence of bound volumes (`tbl4.order`). But we modify our hypotheses as we learn more, and need to shuffle the orderings. I.e. the values of the `order` fields will change, while the unique `id` fields track the bits of the book we are moving around.

Comment: For the toy example the question is: given any word in the text, what would the next 100 words be, given the current state of reconstruction? One solution would be: 1/ query to find the next word (looking into the next strip, page, volume when necessary), 2/ repeat 98 times. A `WHERE` clause with a complex boolean expression on the four `order` fields would be a solution (I think), but @Rick hints that is would be "messy". I suggested using `ROW_NUMBER` to get the position of the words within the text. But the need for two queries with exactly the same repeated subquery had a bad smell.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Hmmm...  an `ORDER BY` that touches multiple tables is probably not optimizable.  That is, my tips don't apply.  And I can't think of any optimization off-hand.

Comment: The "toy example" sounds like a problem that can be solved once (reconstruct the entire text); after that queries are simple to write.  If, instead, you meant that words are being added/deleted/changed dynamically, it gets messier.  (Reminds me of Harry Potter walking through Hogwarts as the Escher-like stairs keep rearranging.)

Comment: Well, you are looking for `WHERE id > 7777` because `id` is actually `@row_number`.  Furthermore, `OFFSET 7777` exactly achieves that.  Sure, it is not efficient, since it must do the joining and count through 7777 rows before doing the "real" work of getting the "next 100".  My technique uses (o1,o2,o3,o4) > (12,23,34,45) (aka, row_num > 7777), then focuses on how to do (o1,o2,o3,o4) > (12,23,34,45) for the next 100 rows.

Comment: Skipping 7777 rows is inefficient; getting the "next 100" can be efficient (but not as described in the 'toy').  Which step do you want made efficient?

Comment: Thanks @Rick. I consider the question answered. 1/ "`ORDER BY` that touches multiple tables probably not optimizeable", 2/ three approaches suggest themselves: a/ your "iterating through a complex key" (complex boolean expression in `WHERE` clause), b/ a "row number" approach, and c/ brute-force reconstructing the entire "book" and querying that. I will try versions of all three, since I don't have the experience to predict which will work best. Yes, Hogwarts/Escher captures the problem: local ordering is mostly stable, but positions in the global sequence can change drastically.